# Git Repository bloat caused by remote update and push

Tags: git, push, synchronize

I was looking at a method to push changes to a backup server in a scripted fashion.  The initial attempts were geared towards a redundant check.  The source server pushed its changes to the remote server.  As a backup check, a git remote update was then run on a 24 hour interval for all repositories living on the remote server.  The goal being to ensure that any failed / missed or interrupted pushes would be caught by the update.  I went in realizing that I would see both local branches and remote branches.  Since users weren't using the repositories, the given commits were associated with the same SHA values and admins had a documented restoration policy to deal with it, I was willing to deal with the added branches.  What surprised me was that I didn't just see a doubling of  branches when running git branch -a but in fact, there was a doubling of the repository size.  Below is the before and after affects of running git remote update after a backup push of all branches :

$ du -sk test.git.old/

2419504 test.git.old/

$ du -sk test.git

5120684 test.git

I'm looking at working around this but the question remains.  Since the SHA values are the same, why am I seeing the code stored twice instead of just referencing the existing SHA value?

Comment: Could you give an example of your push commands? You shouldn't be creating new branches as part of a backup operation. An alternate/simpler setup may be to treat the backup repository as just another client.

Comment: git push remote-alias branch-name  so yes, I am creating a new branch if one is created during the original users push to the repository.  I need to catch and backup all branches for a given repository.

Comment: You know the 2nd repo directory is more than double size, but you don't know that the "code is stored twice". Git objects have unique sha-1 keys and will not store twice. You may want to check for accidental extra .git folder or also try "git gc" to optimize disk usage.

Answer (score 4):

When you use automatic daily updates, it is possible to have some git object database bloat by having lots of loose objects.

Try to repack your git objectstore using

```
git gc
```

or

```
git gc --aggressive
```

Aggressive is not recommended to run regularly, but doing it once in a blue moon is fine (but very slow).

After you do this on both repos, their size should be roughly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that git will only store one object per sha-1 hash. However, git will store the object differently (and different size), depending on whether it is packed. "git gc" is the normal way to force garbage collection and reduce repository size. Just because one repository is bigger doesn't mean it is duplicating objects. A "bare" repo will also be smaller that a working repo.

For your broader goal of having a remote server repository *and* a backup repository, you could have the backup "git pull" just like any other developer. Remember, a cloned repository (which is up to date) will contain all information to replicate the "server" one.

One idea i came up with for you (not in direct use) was to structure the setup like this:

```
developer 1 repo ----->  repo.server  (bare)   <---  repo.backup (bare mirror)
                            ^
developer 2 repo -----------|
```

If your setup it like this, you will easily have a mirror of your "server" repository, which can be used later directly if your "server" repo is lost.

I did a run thru (below), since this is the first time i tried the mirror technique. In my case, there was no repository "bloat". However, you may have different git commands, so it would be useful to compare.

```
$ mkdir repo.local
$ mkdir repo.server
$ mkdir repo.backup
$ git init repo.local/      # initial repo
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/username/code/gittest/repo.local/.git/
$ cd repo.local/
repo.local$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=garbage.dat bs=1M count=2   # 2MB random file
2+0 records in
2+0 records out
2097152 bytes (2.1 MB) copied, 0.486459 s, 4.3 MB/s
repo.local$ git add garbage.dat
repo.local$ git commit -m "+ added 2MB file"
[master (root-commit) 0664e21] + added 2MB file
 1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 garbage.dat
repo.local$ cd ..
$ git init --bare repo.server/      # bare server repo
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/username/code/gittest/repo.server/
$ cd repo.local/
repo.local$ git push ../repo.server/ master  # push to bare repo
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 2.00 MiB, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
To ../repo.server/
 * [new branch]      master -> master
repo.local$ # add repo.server as origin remote, just as if repo.local was a clone of repo.server
repo.local$ git remote add origin /home/username/code/gittest/repo.server/
repo.local$ git pull origin master
From /home/username/code/gittest/repo.server
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
repo.local$ cd ..
$ git push --mirror repo.backup/
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
$ git init --bare repo.backup/   # bare server repo
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/username/code/gittest/repo.backup/
$ git push --mirror repo.backup/
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
$ cd repo.server/
repo.server$ git push --mirror ../repo.backup/
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 2.00 MiB, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
To ../repo.backup/
 * [new branch]      master -> master
repo.server$ cd ..
$ du -sk repo.*
2180    repo.backup
4272    repo.local
2180    repo.server
$ cd repo.local/
repo.local$ git checkout -b topic1
Switched to a new branch 'topic1'
repo.local$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=garbage.dat bs=1M count=3   # 3MB random file
3+0 records in
3+0 records out
3145728 bytes (3.1 MB) copied, 0.729684 s, 4.3 MB/s
repo.local$ git add .
repo.local$ git commit -m "+ revision 2"
[topic1 d9d12d6] + revision 2
 1 files changed, 12161 insertions(+), 8105 deletions(-)
 rewrite garbage.dat (67%)
repo.local$ git branch -a
  master
* topic1
repo.local$ git push origin topic1
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 3.00 MiB, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
To /home/username/code/gittest/repo.server/
 * [new branch]      topic1 -> topic1
repo.local$ git pull origin topic1
From /home/username/code/gittest/repo.server
 * branch            topic1     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
repo.local$ git branch -a
  master
* topic1
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/topic1
repo.local$ cd ..
$ du -sk repo.*
2180    repo.backup
8436    repo.local
5284    repo.server
$ cd repo.server/                                       
repo.server$ git push --mirror ../repo.backup/         
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 3.00 MiB, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
To ../repo.backup/
 * [new branch]      topic1 -> topic1
repo.server$ cd ..
$ du -sk repo.*
5284    repo.backup
8436    repo.local
5284    repo.server
$ cd repo.server/
repo.server$ git branch -a
* master
  topic1
repo.server$ cd ../repo.backup/
repo.backup$ git branch -a
* master
  topic1
repo.backup$
```